# Defined function in python not recognising if and arguments

Tags: python

Always scared to post here, but I'm stumped and also not sure what I'm doing wrong here, because I don't receive any errors. It appears the arguments in this function just don't work. I guess it's because it appears the conditions aren't met?

```
question = [f'{name}, what is 1+1', f'{name}, what is 2+2', f'{name}, what is 2+1']
answer = ['2','4','3']

def generateQuestion():
    question_show = print(random.choice(question))
    answer = input()
    if question_show == question[0] and answer == answer[0]:
        score = score + 1
        print(f"Correct, your score is now {score}")
    if question_show == question[1] and answer == answer[1]:
        score = score + 1
        print(f"Correct, your score is now {score}")    
    if question_show == question[2] and answer == answer[2]:
        score = score + 1
        print(f"Correct, your score is now {score}")
```

If I call that generateQuestion() function is shows the question and allows for input but nothing happens after that.

Comment: Looks like you are missing `else` condition

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

You are not comparing it correctly `answer == answer[0]` will never be `True`. If you read the input in the `answer` then it is no longer holds the old data.

Store the input in other variable like `user_answer` and the compare like `user_answer == answer[0]`

Answer (score 0):

You haven't indented your code that is supposed to be the body of `generateQuestion`. Try this:

```
def generateQuestion():
    question_show = print(random.choice(question))
    answer = input()
```